# Basic Confusion on MERGE SORT’s DIVIDE step

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

In **Merge Sort**, the running time of Divide step for every element is considered **theta(1) i.e constant time** in  CLRS.

---

**My confusion is :** 
Let **divide** is an elementary operation and which takes constant time C1.
Now, Consider the pesudocode
[image]

Now, When **MERGE-SORT** function called for the first time then it will take **C1** to divide the input **(Note:- We are not considering Time taken by Merge function)**
And this **MERGE-SORT** will divide the input **lg(n)** time **(** or we can say it will call itself lg((n)) times **)**
So the total time taken in dividing inputs should be **C1 * lg(n)**
that is **theta(lg(n))**.

---

**But In CLRS :**
[image]

If we consider that then **Divide Step** will require **theta(1) time** ( as whole)

**NOTE: lg is log to the base 2**

***P.S. - Sorry in advance because my English is not upto that mark. Edits are welcome :)***

Comment: Just a comment here, most actual implementations of merge sort in libraries are variations of [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation), where the divide step treats an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, and then starts the merge process. Hybrid bottom up merge sorts might start off by sorting groups of k elements using insertion sort, then using merge sort for the n/k now sorted groups.

Answer (score 1):

The basic understanding of Merge Sort is as such - Consider we have two halves of an array which are already sorted. We can merge these two halves in O(n) time.

Mathematically speaking, the function Merge Sort calls itself twice for two of its halves (The DIVIDE step), and then merges these two (The CONQUER step).

[image: Recurrence Relation]

Now, if we solve this recurrence relation (by using appropriate mathematical analysis), we get the relation as follows:

[image: Solution to Recurrence]

This clearly indicates that the DIVIDE step that takes O(1) time is called n times, while the total merging workload of merging all the smaller halves of various sizes is O(n logn), which is the upper limit. Hence the complexity of O(n logn) (Thanks to [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust) for this clarification).

However, the DIVIDE step takes O(1) time only, which is called O(n) times. Thus, the workload for division is O(n).

Comment: if one divide take C1 time then log n Divides will take C1 * log n that is O(log n) ist't it

Comment: @YiğitArasTunalı Then whole divide step will take O(log n), isn't it?

Comment: The array is not divided O(Log N) times but O(N) times.

Comment: True my bad, I kinda got confused. It is right it will be called `O(n)` times

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please check my edited answer. I understood a lot of things from this.

Comment: @saketk21: it's ok

Answer (score 1):

One step of division indeed takes constant time `O(1)`.

But contrary to your thinking, there are `Θ(N)` divisions in total (`1+2+4+8+...N/2`).

Anyway this is not accounted for as the total merging workload is `Θ(N Log N)`.

Comment: We have total n elements(or say array size n) and to get 1 element(or array size 1) the denominator must be n and here we are dividing n by 2 each time therefore 2^k = n which is equal to k = lg n

Comment: @Bhaskar: your reasoning is wrong. Implement MergeSort and install a counter. (Or read again my answer.)

Comment: I did not understand why the MERGE step will take O(nlogn) time.

Comment: @saketk21: a single merge step takes O(N), and there are O(N) merge steps in total. But not all of the same size.

Comment: Yeah I solved the recurrence relation and figured it out. What do I do next? Delete my answer or edit it?

Comment: @saketk21: as you like.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Exactly! There are a lot of confusing info about this out there. Had me confused for 2 days. Divide doesn't take O(1) or O(logN). It takes O(N - 1), to be exact.